# How to transfer pre trained machine learning model to App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, machine-learning

I have few machine learning models which I have already trained (size in 300MB - 4 GB). Now I want to query them using a rest API. I build my APIs in flask which require these models to be in memory. Is google app engine suitable for it? Or should I use compute engine instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's unsuited for appengine because of reasons like:

1. appengine does not have instances with so much ram (unless you use flexible which is basically the same as gce option).
2. even if it did, the instance can go away which requires to reload data to memory constantly (thou it could be on memcached)
3. time restrictions on frontend instances will make it very unlikely you can even get time to load data to memory, less being able to analyze the data. a backend type of instance could do it, but will be harder than doing it from a regular VM.
4. good luck loading the libraries you need, as none should write to file storage, even for a temp file.

thus compute engine is the correct place.